# Analyticity implying Constant

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, analyticity

Question: $f(z)$ is analytic in $C$ and $Im(f(z))\leq 0$. I want to show that $f(z)$ is a constant.

Approach: I know that if $f$ is analytic on a closed curve then the line integral along that curve of $f$ is $0$. But I how do I use the fact that the $f$ is analytic on the lower half plane? And how exactly does it imply that $f$ is constant?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thankyou

Comment: Do you know Liouville's theorem? And the statement you refer to should be "if $f$ has *a primitive* on some neighborhood of a closed curve". See, for example $1/z$ on the unit circle.

Comment: yes i know the louville's theorem, it says if f is bounded then f is constant, given f is entire. over here we have f analytic. also i don't get what u mean by f has a primitive??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**: Is $\exp(-i f(z))$ bounded?

---

Let $f(z) = u(z) + i v(z)$ where $u$ and $v$ are real functions. We have:

$$
\exp(-if(z)) = \exp(-iu(z))\exp(v(z))
$$

Hence:

$$
\left|\exp(-if(z))\right| = \exp(v(z))
$$

Since $v(z) \le 0$. It follows that $\exp(-if(z))$ is bounded. By Liouville's theorem, it's constant. Thus $f$ is constant.

Comment: no since the $Im(f)\leq 0$ then $exp(-if(z))$ is unbounded. right?

Comment: @d13 It's actually bounded. I've added a complete proof.

Comment: yes thankyou. i understand it now. thanks a lot.

Comment: @d13 You're welcome. Glad it helped.